# How can I add new files to a split rar archive?

Tags: rar

I created a `.rar` archive with the `-v` option, so it was split into several `filename.part0X.rar` files.
Now I need to add some new files to the archive from a subdirectory, but the command fails. I tried with:

```
rar a -r -t -v1024000k -m5 filename.part09.rar *dir_path*
```

but got the error:

```
ERROR: Cannot modify volume
Program aborted
```

I also tried with `rar u`, instead of `rar a`, but nothing changed.

Where am I wrong?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. Why not?

Comment: Read `man rar`, especially the `-en` switch, and the caveat about volumes. The last volume contains special data used in reconstructing the archive. You must rebuild the archive, then add the file.