# which archive format is appendable, indexed, seekable and multi-volume

Tags: archive, zip

I am looking for a multi-volume, indexed, seekable and appendable archive format.

1. **multi-volume** = split the TB-size archive into GB-chunks
2. **indexed** = add complete index at the archive end with offset information per file in the archive stream
3. **seekable** = allow fast extraction of file ABC from chunk 15 and 16 with only those chunks plus the last chunk being present
4. **appendable** = add data and update the index after initial archive creation

There is a [similar question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1338685/) here on Askubuntu but limited to rar which apparently ticks all four boxes but isn't appendable and multi-volume at the same time.  [tar](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/) is appendable but needs to read in the entire archive for extraction of any part.  multi-volume zip files are apparently [uneditable](https://www.tc4shell.com/en/help/basics/how-to-create-a-multi-volume-archive/) and [so is 7-zip](https://sourceforge.net/p/sevenzip/discussion/45797/thread/1b2e567a/).  [zpaq](http://mattmahoney.net/dc/zpaq.html) is pretty close but apparently the stream needs to be present in its entirety for extraction.  An interesting approach is [gzipi](https://rushter.com/blog/gzip-indexing/) which cats gzipped chunks together and adds an index to it.  The idea might be generalized for a new tool but the implementation seems to be specialized towards logs and text files only.